# Unraveling inline anonymous functions into named functions

Tags: swift

The following code correctly prints true or false, depending if the string contains a vowel. This is a shorthand format using anonymous functions, closures, captured variables, etc.

```
let s = "hello"
println(contains(s,{contains("aeiou",$0)}))
```

I'm trying to unravel it into a separate named function with explicit parameters

```
let s = "hello"
func myFunction(c: Character)->Bool {
    return contains(s,c)
}

println(contains(s,myFunction(???))
```

What is the appropriate function definition and subsequent call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe @stklieme doesn't address the OP's question, because the code passes params in reverse order. Invoking anonymous closures using external functions requires you to name the parameters in the closure like this:

```
let s = "hello"

//println(contains(s, {contains("aeiou",$0)}))

func myFunction(c: Character) -> Bool {
    return contains("aeiou", c)
}

println(contains(s, { (c: Character) -> Bool in return myFunction(c) }))
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use either a "traditional" function passing two parameters

```
func myFunction(c: Character, string : String) -> Bool
{
  return contains(s,c)
}

println(myFunction("f", "Hello")) // false
```

or a closure which can capture the string parameter

```
let s = "hello"
var myClosureFunction = { (c: Character) -> Bool in
  return contains(s,c)
}

println(myClosureFunction("o")) // true
```